# Using data string as property in jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am returning a direction string to a function and i wish to replace the `left` property for the jquery animate with the string in the returned value.

i tried the following which did not work

```
// my attempt at using string returned for property
        function direction (data) {
           // move the object in the direction given by x
            $( "#cube" ).animate({
                data.direction: "+=5" // here changed from left -> data.direction which has the direction string inside [left up right down] 
              }, 10, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            });
        }


// original working example
    function direction (data) {
       // move the object in the direction given by x
        $( "#cube" ).animate({
            left: "+=5"
          }, 10, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an object with property set to `data.direction` , set value to `"+=5"`

```
   function direction (data) {
     var opts = {}; opts[data.direction] = "+=5";
     // move the object in the direction given by x
     $( "#cube" ).animate(opts, 10, function() {
       // Animation complete.
     });
   }
```

alternatively,

```
var data = {
  left:{left:""},
  right:{right:"+=5"},
  up:{up:""},
  down:{down:""}
}

function direction (data) {
  // move the object in the direction given by x
  $( "#cube" ).animate(right, 10, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}

direction(data.right)
```